# Can any one help me.it shows every time I scan

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, operating-systems, help-files

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Comment: Does it still do this if you first delete the log files? Have you looked at the logs to see what it found? Run `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"` to strip to only problems. Post any problems to your question.

Comment: dcdCAJCBDWVCDC;S C

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be coming from System File Checker. I never found any point trying to sort through that log. It is just a big long list of everything it looked at.

Try running DISM error correction.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and then run in the order
> below.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Please let us know if that fixes your issues or if more in-depth repairs are needed.

Comment: s mdkm xjndhubvcyebh x]labx dki eoicjbdycbdojc Tbehhcir kjthe cnjdcojsjcjdhbcjbdu8vbh eicjuydvoudfherjcuhdh c pdkciuhwd

Comment: IHDINCJN DJH jhcbjhd

Comment: ijdwjcsadsckn vjhd s